# How to run WSGI-file with Nginx

Tags: nginx, python, uwsgi, wsgi

I have a Python-application with a Bottle-webserver running with port 8080. Now i will connect Nginx to the Bottle-webserver with a wsgi-file.

Now, i have a wsgi-file, but how can i execute this with Nginx? Which commands in the Nginx- configuration (default.conf) do i need? Maybe my way of thinking is wrong.
Can someone give me some clarity?

I have this in the Nginx-config:

```
server {
  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
```

For now i see the error `(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream)` in the logs.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: This is NOT off-topic, this is just question about servers, and not about other things like cows and calfs. I think this is a mistake ;-)?

Anyway... for now i have an error, and i don't know why!
I'm just curious to the solution  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your Bottle server is either not running, or listening on a port other than 8080.

Comment: Is there a possibilty to run this Bottle-server automatic when i start nginx?

Comment: Of course. Don't they have example init scripts?

Comment: Only a wsgi script. And i have installed Uwsgi. But how can i run the Bottle-script automatically permanent by starting Nginx?

Comment: Nginx cannot start your Python process. You have to write a startup script or service configuration suitable for your OS.

Comment: I'll will try....